# How would I read this formula?

Tags: notation

$$m=\Bigg[\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\Bigg]^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

I do understand notation similar to this. Like summation formulas using sigma, but this is new to me. Also, how would I read this formula too?

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx$$

Comment: Does "read" mean "speak" or "comprehend" or "parse" or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Geometric Mean Filtering]

So $m = (x_1x_2x_3...x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$.  Note that it's basically the same as sigma notation, except the operation is now multiplication instead of addition.  Whereas with sigma notation, we would say "the sum from $i=1$ to $n$", we now say "the product from $i=1$ to $n$".

The second one would be read as "the integral of $f(x)$ evaluated from $a$ to $b$".

Comment: So how would I read the integral formula then? (P.S. Thank you for the first answer!)

Comment: @Mtn_Wolf You still haven't told us which meaning of "read" that you intend - see my comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The first one means $(x_1x_2 \cdots x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$, multiplication.  The second is the integral of $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b$.